# If there is a minus symbol on a seed, should I ignore that when I put a seed in the "server.properties" file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

If there is a minus symbol on a seed, should I ignore that when I put a seed in the "server.properties" file? Or should I leave it in?

The seed looks like this: **-7608072235823377213**

I tried that seed where it said "level-seed=" in the "server.properties" file, but I got something else... Not the world that was showing when I put that seed
in in a single-player world, or the one in the YouTube video I watched.

Comment: Here is video i watched: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgQQw0rzdXg

Comment: Are you sure that the server files you have are for 1.12.2?

Answer (score 1):

you need to keep the '-' sign.

discrepancies in world appearence can be because of spawn coordinates, minecraft version or mod list/mod config. Make sure to use the same 'environment' as the videomaker and /tp to the coordinates that video was recorded at.

Comment: Uuumh. How do i find coordinates and tp to that place???

Comment: That video do not showing any coordinates.  As that video showing if i use that seed i will spawn beside a mountain.  I don't see that mountain when i use that seed when i create server.

Comment: server spawn coordinates are sometimes a bit different than client coordinates - at least they were on some minecraft versions. Are you using the same version as the videomaker? Do you trust the video?

Comment: I use the latest version of Minecraft. It's 1.12.2

Comment: When i use that seed on "Singleplayer" world i get exactly that mountain and world as showing on that video. And i use 1.12.2 version.  But if i create a server with that seed i get something else.

Comment: try to note down the spawn coordinates from the single player world (press f3) and then go there in the server world. if that doesn't help, make sure you have the same terrain generation settings and are not using an existing world with another seed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the world in your local client, and then copy it on to the server world. Remember to put the correct seed in level-seed=

**Edit 1: You need to put the minus symbol**